# After trying to remove SELinux, system doesn't start; shows error of “unable to connect to system bus”

Tags: selinux, dbus

I had SELinux installed on my system which actually was a bit annoying. I tried to remove it. After that my system is unable to start. The error that is showing up is:

`unable to connect to system bus : Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket : No such file or directory`

I tried to check the status for the `dbus` service by `service dbus status` and it returned `dbus service running`

What should I do?

Comment: Exactly what did you do?

Comment: The OS is started if you got to the point of getting a DBUS error and being able to run `service`. What else are you trying to run?

Comment: @Michael `sudo apt-get purge selinux` was what I did

@Chris Well other crucial services were not able to run.Such as the `network service`,`smbd` and for most `Xserver` was not able to start.

Answer (score 0):

Removing SELinux (by wiping out the package) is ***NOT*** the correct way to deal with it.
If you want SELinux disabled, disable it (or set it to "permissive" mode).

I would suggest reinstalling the package (you may have to boot to a recovery disk for this).

Comment: Well thanks for all your suggestion. But nothing seemed to work so I finally formatted my system.